# How to use Java Stream to check whether all data in a field in an list of objects are present in a field of a different object?

Tags: java

I have a list of `FileOne` which has a member `fileId` and another list of `MappingFile` which has a member `fileId`. I want to check if all `fileId`s in `fileData` are present in the `mappingData` and also return the ones which are not mapped. How do i do this?

```
List<FileOne> fileData = getFileOneDocuments();
List<MappingFile> mappingData = getMappingFileDocuments();
boolean isAllMapped = fileData.stream().map(FileOne::getFileId).allMatch(mappingData::getFileId::contains);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```java
List<FileOne> fileData = new ArrayList<>();
List<MappingFile> mappingData = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> mappingDataFileIds = mappingData.stream().map(MappingFile::getFileId).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<FileOne> notMappedFileData = fileData.stream()
        .filter(fileOne -> !mappingDataFileIds.contains(fileOne.getFileId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
boolean isAllMapped = notMappedFileData.isEmpty();
```

The easiest way is to filter `fileData` to remove the ones in `mappingData` and then check if the filtered list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can inverse it like this :

```
        List<FileOne> fileData = getFileOneDocuments();
        List<MappingFile> mappingData = getMappingFileDocuments();
        List<Integer> notMapped = fileData.stream().map(FileOne::getFileId).filter(f-> mappingData.stream.noneMatch(m->m.getFileId().equals(f)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        boolean isAllMapped = !notMapped.isEmpty();
```

this will return the list of all the fileID not mapped. in case you want the FileOne object you can avoid maping them

Comment: This return only the `FileId`s as List of `Integer` but I need the whole object as List of `FileOne`.